# Swift Tableview cell button image changed based on tableview data

Tags: ios, json, swift, tableview

I am trying to parse JSON and appending JSON response value within tableview  array. Here below response `subcategory` few objects I am getting values but some of them I am getting null.

```
{
    "category": [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "subcategory": [   //Table cell button need to show green color
    {
    "subcategory_id": 10
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "id": 0,
    "subcategory": null //Table cell button need to show red color
    }
    ]
}
```

1. I need to append the values into array `like : [10, null,....]`. if subcategory null means I need to store null otherwise its value.
2. After applying to cell, If the value is null need to change cell button Image.

I tried my best to resolved out of range but I didn't get well result for above scenario.

Here is my code

```
 if indexPath.row < id.count {
            cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row]) // If the cell.accessibilityValue not null then need to change cell button image.
        }
        cell.name_Label.text = name[indexPath.row]
        cell.city_Label.text = city[indexPath.row]
```

Array appending from JSON `self.id.append(items)`. I am getting output `like [10]` but actual result should be `[10,null]`. The length of the array which is not right, i need the data to be "null" if it is null or nil because i get values by index and each index is know to be null or with value but it must be there

Comment: have your appended the items to your array ? print your array here

Comment: updated post please check it. @ShahzaibQureshi

Comment: each item in your array is a String ? or dictionary ?

Comment: Its String not a dictionary @ShahzaibQureshi

Comment: then you can check like :

if id[indexPath.row] == null {
//setImage
}else{
}

Comment: If I print my array I am getting result like [10] but actually it should show [10, null] because one index I have value and another one index need to show null but its not storing null values, So the length of the array which is not right, i need the data to be "null" if it is null or nil because i get values by index and each index is know to be null or with value but it must be there @ShahzaibQureshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `id` should be an array of `optional Int`
2. `subcategory_id` should be `optional Int`

   ```
   var subcategory_id: Int?
   var id: [Int?] = []

   if let subCat = subcategory_id {
      id.append(subCat)
   } 
    else {
           id.append(nil) // id=[nil]
         }
   ```

   in your cellForAtRow overload

   `id` is an array of `optional Int`(`Int?`) you have to unwrap it

   ```
   cell.id_Label.text = id[indexPath.row]!
   ```

   or

   ```
   if let i = id[indexPath.row] {
     cell.id_Label.text = "\(i)"
   }
   else { 
         print("id is nil")
       }
   ```

Comment: but while I am assigning values to cell label getting    cell.id_Label.text = String(id[indexPath.row])
Error: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int?)' @Hamed Akhlaghi

Comment: use this "\\(id[indexPath.row])" instead of String(id[indexPath.row]), this code will be add nil to cell.id_Label.text if there is no value for id

Comment: Thats great. but I am getting result Optional(values) also cell.id_Label.text = String("\(id[indexPath.row])" ), warnings String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit? @Hamed Akhlaghi

Comment: if \(id[indexPath.row]) != nil { cell.id_Label.text  = "\(id[indexPath.row])!"} else {  cell.id_Label.text  = ""} you should unwrap (id[indexPath.row]) or set a default value

Comment: No its not working getting same optionals @Hamed Akhlaghi

  if (id[indexPath.row]) != nil {
                cell.id_Label.text = String("\(id[indexPath.row])" )
                cell.id_Label.textColor = UIColor.red
            } else {
                cell.id_Label.text = ""
                cell.id_Label.textColor = UIColor.green
            }

Comment: test this code: if let i = id[indexPath.row] { cell.id_Label.text = "\\(id[indexPath.row])!"} else { print("id is nil") }

Comment: Same issues showing Optional(0)!
Optional(1)!
Optional(2)!
Optional(3)!
@Hamed Akhlaghi